# Installation failed due to: 'null' - Android Studio 3.5

Tags: android, android-studio

I have updated Android studio to 3.5, ever since I am running into an APK installation problem. This is the only log it shows:

```
Installation did not succeed.
The application could not be installed: INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_UNEXPECTED_EXCEPTION
Installation failed due to: 'null'
Retry
```

This happens when trying to install APK on a real device. If I uninstall the app from the device and then rerun the build, it installs only one time and then it keeps throwing this error on the next installation. It runs fine on an emulator but I can not use an emulator for everything.

What I have tried:

- Deleted Android Studio configuration file.
- Deleted Gradle files from the project.
- Invalidated and reset caches.
- Cleaned/rebuilt the project.
- Looked for similar problems Stackoverflow(nothing matches my problem)
- Clean installed(Removed all files including SDKs) Android Studio 3.5

**Update**

I installed Linux Mint on my machine and tested the AS 3.5 there, for some reason everything is working fine even for Android 7 and below devices.

Previous OS: Windows 10 1903

Current OS: Linux Mint 19.2

I reckon this problem may be originating from Windows machines.

Comment: I have similar problem - but for me it's `INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_NOT_APK` while running Espresso tests

Comment: I'm also getting `INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_NOT_APK`

Comment: I'm also getting the same issue.

Comment: wow Google, how can you make this a **STABLE** release?!

Comment: Did you check if the Instant Run is enabled in your Android Studio?

Comment: @ReazMurshed there is no instant run in android studio 3.5

Comment: But I think I saw a similar thing like instant run when I updated my Android Studio. Let me check again.

Comment: @ManoharReddy I think the apply changes is the same thing as Instant Run.

Comment: @ReazMurshed Actually it's completely different from instant run , its a complete rewite from scratch

Comment: I see. Thanks for the information. Will dig for a better understanding once I have some time.

Comment: It's because that your _Instant Run_ will not be enabled.

Comment: In android studio 3.5 instant run is removed so how to handle error

Comment: Oh I see. I haven't updated yet. But i got same error yesterday in 3.4 so above my comment worked!

Comment: Looks like this feature is broken as well as instant run. I have to clean build every time (which is on each run) to successfully install APK on the device.

Comment: See my answer below. I found the solution here: https://developer.android.com/studio/run#apply-changes-run-fallback. Tested on a device running Android 9. I haven't tested it on other version.

Comment: Finally, I got the solution in the code edit run configuration changing in Installation option DEPLOY--> from select 4th option -->(Nothing) option --> Apply And the app works properly in android studio 3.5. In mobile and emulator also. This work properly in android version 9 also This is a permanent solution.

Comment: Apart from all the answers shared here, this error can also occur if your device support a different compile version than what is mentioned in the build.grade file. This can be tested by running the app on AVD with an emulator matching the API version mentioned in the file. If it runs fine, then to run it on your device you need to lower the API version to match with the one that is supported by the device.

Answer (score 108, accepted):

Open **Run/Debug Configuration** dialog (Windows: <kbd>Run</kbd>  > <kbd>Edit Configurations</kbd>)

edit **You app > <kbd>General</kbd> > <kbd>Installation Options</kbd> > <kbd>Install Flags</kbd>** .

add install flags `-r -t`.

This flags means `adb install -r -t apkpath`

[image: screen pic]

Comment: This flags means `adb install -r -t apkpath`,I guess.@TaseerAhmad

Comment: `-r` means "replace existing application". `-t` means "allow test packages"

Comment: Where did this man come from and how did he think of this solution? Give him a medal!

Comment: Not working for me! :( Please look at my problem. Its a little different than yours.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57770464/installation-did-not-succeed-the-application-could-not-be-installed-installati/57770776#57770776

Comment: It's working for app install but not for tests. When I try to run androidTest.

Comment: The setting is Run > Edit Configurations, if windows version.

Answer (score 24):

You need disable "Use libusb backend" in preferences--> debugger
[image]

Comment: Only this solution helped - Xubuntu 18.04

Comment: Cant believe this worked! Android Studio 3.5.1 Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.41
Version 29.0.5-5949299

Comment: Works like charm. Struggled with this problem for months and only this answer worked for me

Comment: OMG! this has solved a big big problem. Struggled with this problem for months as wel.. Wow!

Comment: Fixed this for me on OSx 10.15! Thank you!

Answer (score 12):

This issue in Android Studio happens for devices lower then `API 26` (Android 8). This is caused by replacement of `InstantRun`, known now as [ApplyChanges](https://developer.android.com/studio/run#apply-changes).

Seems to be there are only two ways before they fix it in the next update.

1. Run on `API>=26`.
2. After every change in code edit `run configuration` changing `deploy` from `APK` to `App bundle` and vise-versa. If I correctly understand, this will correctly rebuild app and workaround bug.

Of course, there is an option to manually delete app from device before running app from AndroidStudio.

Comment: I have an Android 9.0 device and have this problem.

However, when I mix running tests between emulator and then real device, app and tests appear to be running quite often. I don't really know why but maybe it will help someone.

Comment: Maybe you can successfully rerun app on `API26+` if you click `Apply changes`, instead of `rerun`? This is new button to right of `rerun`.

Answer (score 11):

**Build > Clean project** its work's for me. Before change other setting try this first.

Happy coding :)

Answer (score 7):

For me either uninstalling the app or cleaning project "solves" the problem. To make it less frustrating I added clean job to debug build type like so:

```
buildTypes {
    ...
    debug {
        clean
    }
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 6):

After reading the [Release Notes](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases#apply-changes) regarding **Apply Changes**, I finally found a solution here: https://developer.android.com/studio/run#apply-changes-run-fallback

> ### Enable Run fallback for Apply Changes
>
> After you've clicked either Apply Changes and Restart Activity or
>   Apply Code Changes, Android Studio builds a new APK and determines
>   whether the changes can be applied. If the changes can't be applied
>   and would cause Apply Changes to fail, Android Studio prompts you to
>   Run Run icon your app again instead. However, if you don't want to be
>   prompted every time this occurs, you can configure Android Studio to
>   automatically rerun your app when changes can't be applied.
>
> To enable this behavior, follow these steps:
>
> 1. Open the Settings or Preferences dialog:
>
>    - On Windows or Linux, select **File > Settings** from the menu bar.
>    - On macOS, select **Android Studio > Preferences** from the menu bar.
> 2. Navigate to **Build, Execution, Deployment > Deployment**.
> 3. Select the *checkboxes* to enable automatic Run fallback for either of
>      the Apply Changes actions.
> 4. Click OK.

[image: Screenshot running on Linux]

Comment: I have changed OS to Linux and AS 3.5 is working fine there.

Answer (score 4):

There is a problem with Lineage OS as stated by Google team in https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/139782879:

> We are able to reproduce it on a device with LineageOS.
>   It does not fully support a system call that we use for DeltaInstall.

There is no apparent solution (other than removing the APK from build folder or uninstalling the application).

> We should have a workaround for it but as it stands right now, LineageOS will not have DeltaInstall and will always need to perform a slower full install.

Changing to `Nothing` as pointed out by OP will not deploy the APK to the device (that's why an error will not be displayed), so it will not solve the problem.

**Edit:**

This has been fixed in Android Studio 3.6.

> Thanks for the feedback. This should be fixed in the latest versions of 3.6.

Answer (score 3):

I got the solution in the code edit run configuration changing in Deploy select Default APK and **install flag =-r -t** and then Apply for the run. The app will run in all devices and emulator. **I was testest in OPPO 1 plus, Samsung Tab, Emulator Also**.

Please Go thought the **Edit Run configuration** 
near to run button in Android Studio

**edit app > general ==> installation options ==> Install flags**

**add install flags -r -t**

**-r means "replace existing application". -t means "allow test packages"**

[image]

Answer (score 3):

1-clean project from **Build -> CleanProject**

2-delete folder **outputs** from **ProjectPath/app/build/outputs**

3-then build gradle and run app

Answer (score 2):

I too am having this same problem after upgrading to 3.5.  I was wondering if you have had any luck getting 'Run' to work with a connected device?

UPDATE:  I was am to get this to work by Setting "APK from app bundle" under Installation Options in the "Run/Debug Configurations" dialog

Answer (score 2):

I also got this error when I ran the application on real xiaomi pocophone 1 and solved this problem by running the application first on the emulator, and then on my xiaomi pocophone 1

Answer (score 2):

I got this because the device was locked and required user to accept permissions in order to install it. (Huawei Harmony OS)

Unlocking the phone to prepare for the installation process solved the issue.

Answer (score 2):

If your app targets Android 12 or higher, you must declare these attribution tags in your app's manifest file. If the app component includes the LAUNCHER category, set android:exported to true.

```
 <activity
    android:name="com.test.activity.SplashActivity"
    android:clearTaskOnLaunch="true"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:launchMode="singleTop"
    android:noHistory="true"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
    android:exported="true">
```

Also check receiver or service in Androidmanifest, if you are using any receiver or service set android:exported="true" or false according requirement.

```
<receiver
    android:name="com.test.receiver.ShareReceiver"
    android:exported="true">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.test.fcm.android.action.broadcast" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>

 <service
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.tagmanager.InstallReferrerService"
    android:exported="true" />
```

Also update all your gradle dependency.
I have updated following dependency as per requirement.

```
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2' 
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.4.0'


androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
implementation 'com.razorpay:checkout:1.6.15'
```

Hope it will help you as well.

Answer (score 1):

Deleting/uninstalling the app from the device fixed the problem for me.

Comment: I uninstalled the app from API 29 emulator and it helped.

Answer (score 1):

Add a "**clean**" gradle task dependency **before installing/running** your apks using below configuration.

```
project.afterEvaluate {
    android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.each { output ->
            def capitalizedVariant = variant.name.capitalize()
            def assembleVariantTask = project.tasks."assemble${capitalizedVariant}"
            assembleVariantTask.dependsOn clean
        }
    }
}
```

**Copy and paste** above code into your `app/build.gradle` file, **this works for all the build variants.**

In specifically, above code will be equivalent to below if you only have debug and release build types:

```
assembleDebug.dependsOn clean
assembleRelease.dependsOn clean
```

Answer (score 1):

What Worked for me to remove old application, then rerun the project. In that case old sign certificate does not bother.

Answer (score 1):

```
splits {
    abi {
        enable true
        reset()
        include 'x86', 'armeabi-v7a','x86_64'
        universalApk true
    }
}
```

Due to the different constructions such as 'armeabi', 'x86', 'armeabi-v7a', 'x86_64', and 'arm64-v8a', we have to add the configuration above into build.gradle file.

Answer (score 1):

For me I added accidentally new `BlankActivity` which is inherited from `Wearable Activity`. Then I deleted the activity code and layout file. But I forgot to delete the wearable related tag in App `Manifest.xml` file. This is the main problem for someone like me.

Answer (score 0):

At last, I found the solution

just set v2SigningEnabled true

```
 signingConfigs {
    release {
        v2SigningEnabled true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I did not face the problem myself. However, previously we had some problems with the Instant Run of the Android Studio. I would like to suggest checking the following settings in your Android Studio and uncheck the settings to check if your code works now.

Go to the `Android Studio -> Preference` and then uncheck the following under the `Deployments`.

[image]

Here's what is new in Android Studio 3.5 regarding this which will help you to understand the feature better.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try to run the command "adb devices", if the output is empty, then reconnect the device. This helped me with the same error. Android studio 3.5 does not determine that the device has disconnected.

Answer (score 0):

It bug still have on my mac os, when i get new real device and try install apk from android studio 3.5 - and I find ugly way how it fix - open terminal in studio and follow:

```
cd app/build/outputs/apk/debug
adb install -r -t your_app_name.apk
```

And it need to do with each project and each device!!

**Edited:**

I eventually installed

> Android Studio 3.6 Canary

- it's more working version than 3.5

But stiil need add into *install flags* `-r -t`

Comment: We have to wait for a 'stable' 3.6 release.

Answer (score 0):

I uninstalled the app from emulator, ran and everything went back to normal

Answer (score 0):

For me `minSdkVer = 22, tarSdkVer = 28`,run `Gradle -> app -> Tasks -> build -> clean && cleanBuildCache` action, problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

I pressed the hammer icon to rebuild the app then it installed.  So I don't know? The whole android hack job platform sucks.

All that money yet google can't hire or find programmers good enough to come up with their own true operating system.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it only works by disabling the APK signature verification:

```
$ adb shell settings put global verifier_verify_adb_installs 0
```

And using the `-r -t` flags mentioned above

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same issue , i followed the following steps 
1) Clean Project 
2) Rebuilt Project

This solved my problem

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I can't solve with all of the above answers so that I find another way. Finally, I found the solution. **Just find the correct drivers of phone.** My **development phone is Samsung Galaxy Note 2 (MODEL : GT-N7105 / Android 4.1.2)**. I just share my solution to how I solved it. Hope save your time.

Answer (score 0):

The problem occurs when you are testing a new module. First, you write it individually, and then add it to the main app. When you add it to the main app, delete your "test_app" from your phone.

Answer (score 0):

Run -> Edit Configuration -> install flags: -r -t  -> Apply -> Ok

Answer (score 0):

I got this problem a few minutes ago when I tried running my app on real device and stopped gradle build before it finished. What I just did was to uninstall the app on device and  rerun the app on both AVD and real device (simultaneously) and it worked. Hope this works for you too

Answer (score 0):

## Main Solution

1. **File -> Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment** -> **Debugger** > Disable **`Use libusb backend`**
2. **Gradle** (Flap to the right of the IDE) **-> android -> app -> Tasks -> install -> uninstallAll** or you can also do it by console in the following way:

   `$ ./gradlew uninstallAll`

---

---

#### Other Tips:

- Delete and create the app again in Run/Debug Configuration

  - Installation Options -> Check **Install for all users**
- Run/Debug Configuration -> Launch Options > Launch: Specified Activity > Choose an Activity
- Install app using another physical device, version of the IDE or PC
- Reinstall IDE and delete .android
- Retry with the main solution

---

If you want to install and open the app you can use adb with the following commands:

```
$ adb install -r -t absolute-path.apk

$ adb shell am start -n "com.package.flavor.env/.MainActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
```

GL

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60988086/5279996)

Answer (score 0):

For me the issue started when I created a new blank activity and Android studio created a Wearable activity for some reason. Once I removed all mentions to wearable activity from the manifest and I deleted the class everything went back to normal.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same symptom, but the cause and solution is completely different from what others have been experiencing, so I'm posting this solution just to add to the knowledge base of known things that can cause this error.

I'm running Android studio Android Studio Giraffe | 2022.3.1 Patch 2 on Windows 11.

I don't get any Build errors when I build the project, and the error consistently happens when I try to debug the app. None of the proposed solutions such as cleaning the project, invalidate caches, adding -r -t adb option, etc. resolved the issue. The general belief and proposed solutions seems to be centered around the ideas that somehow your project or android studio itself has been corrupted.  In my case, that's not the situation!

What's different from this particular project, compared to many other projects I've made, is that the project contains an Android Service.  In the manifest for the service configuration I had added the attribute "android:process = "networkDiscovery".  When I change it to "android:process = ":networkDiscovery", I  would no longer get Installation Failed error.

So in my case, the cause of the problem was related to a manifest configuration issue. In my particular case I observed this problem with trying to configure the Android Service process. I would suspect that there may be other related manifest configuration issues that may also cause this problem.

Answer (score -1):

try to chang android:`appComponentFactory=""` to `android:appComponentFactory="new"`,`"new"` can be any words

Answer (score -2):

Finally, I got the solution in the code edit run configuration changing in Installation option DEPLOY--> from select 4th option -->(Nothing) option --> Apply
And the app works properly in android studio 3.5. In mobile and emulator also. This work properly in android version 9 also
This is a permanent solution.

Answer (score -2):

gradle.properties -> android.enableAapt2=false

Comment: **DO NOT USE THIS!** Aapt has been deprecated in favor of aapt2, and will eventually be removed. This workaround will stop working, and cause other problems when aapt is removed