# Installation did not succeed. The application could not be installed. Installation failed due to: '-26' Retry

Tags: android, macos, android-studio, android-emulator

I can not debug my code in my new macOS android studio!
And my debug fields display the information"

> 12/08 20:16:58: Launching 'app' on Pixel 2 API 29. Installation did
>   not succeed. The application could not be installed. Installation
>   failed due to: '-26' Retry"

But I get my java environmental variable, it can not debug, too!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Installation failed due to: 'null' - Android Studio 3.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57589248/installation-failed-due-to-null-android-studio-3-5)

Answer (score 4):

Simply uninstall the app from the phone and the try reinstalling it from Android Studio. This will definitely do the trick.