# Installation did not succeed In Android API 27,28,29

Tags: android

I have problem cannot installed my App to android with API 27,28,29 with error log :

> 05/11 17:59:07: Launching 'app' on Pixel 2 API 29.
>   Installation did not succeed.
>   The application could not be installed: INSTALL_FAILED_NO_MATCHING_ABIS
>   Installation failed due to: 'null'
>   Retry

it was tested in my android studio simulator and my real device.
but it is working well when I install it to android API <27

Comment: Does your app contain native c/c++ code? Which ABIs are supported by the native libs?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57589248/installation-failed-due-to-null-android-studio-3-5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the answer seems ridiculous but it happened. the problem comes if I take out one of my dependency that I actually do not use it.
that is

> implementation 'pl.droidsonroids.gif:android-gif-drawable:1.2.8'

so I put it back to my Gradle app and then everything works normally. but I still need precisely answer why this happens

Answer (score 0):

try to add this in `build.gradle` in `android` block

```
splits {
abi {
    enable true
    reset()
    include 'x86', 'armeabi-v7a', 'x86_64'
    universalApk true
}
```

}