# Android Studio: Installation failed due to: 'device 'xxxxxxxx' not found'

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm struggling with an issue connecting Android Studio to my Google Pixel 2.

When I plug my phone into my laptop, Android Studio now recognizes the physical device and shows 'Google Pixel 2' in the dropdown of devices to run the app on. When I go to run the app, it compiles without error but when it tries to install the app on my phone the connection between my phone and AS is lost (the device is no longer listed in the dropdown) and this error message is shown in the Run dialog:

```
06/12 17:08:35: Launching 'app' on Google Pixel 2.
Installation did not succeed.
The application could not be installed.

List of apks:
[0] '/home/kirk/Apps/xxxx/android/app/build/outputs/apk/debug/app-debug.apk'
Installation failed due to: 'device 'xxxxxxxx' not found'
Retry
```

Clicking the `Retry` link just results in it being launched in an emulator.

I've tried disconnecting and reconnecting the device, revoking the USB debugging authorisations then re-trusting my computer, as well as closing and re-opening Android Studio.

Any ideas?

Comment: I have the same issue I bought a new usb cable, the last one was lost connection if I moved

Comment: I'll try a different cable :)

Comment: Tried a different cable, same results :/

Comment: sorry to hear that, update your Android Studio or Gradle, reset your phone, test all dumb solutions...because it's weird

Comment: Same here. Tried with 3 different cables. Rebooting Android Studio and device. Nothing was working.

Comment: same here ... :(

Comment: Try File->Invalidate Cache and restart from Android studio.

Comment: I fixed it by following the post https://stackoverflow.com/a/58095554/2400353

Answer (score 12):

Android Studio–>Preferences–>Build,Execution,Deployment–>Debugger–>“Use libusb backend”, select false–>Apply–>Ok

Comment: I think it has been removed since 2020.1.3 because I don't have this option!

Comment: This worked for me on Electric Eel on MacOS.

Comment: This worked to me.

Comment: I'm on Android Studio Flamingo | 2022.2.1 Patch 2 on MacOS. The option was disabled by default, *enabling* it fixed it for me 

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes ADB just need a restart.

`adb kill-server`

`adb start-server`

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had a plugin to connect via wifi, like:

**Android WIFI ADB**

Try to uninstall this type of plugin then clean Android Studio on *Invalidate Caches / Restart...*

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me when I was sharing Wi-Fi from my PC to the phone.
When I disconnected my phone from my PC's Wi-Fi, everything worked.

It could be an issue with ADB rather than Android Studio

Answer (score -1):

I think it is problem with adb not with android studio I tried updating adb it worked for me. Try once