# Cant install normal app after running instant app once (Installation failed due to: '-27')

Tags: android, android-instant-apps

**What I want to achieve**

A android project which consists of a normal app and a instant app version of it which will be a demo version of the normal app.

**The problem**

On a fresh emulator/device I **can** run the app without any problem. I also **can** run the instant app after deinstalling the normal app without any problem. **But** I cant install the normal app after running the instant app once on the device. The only thing that helps is wiping the data on the emulator.

This is the error I receive:

```
08/10 17:25:12: Launching 'app' on Pixel 3a API 27.
Installation did not succeed.
The application could not be installed.

List of apks:
[0] '/<path-to-project/instant/app/build/outputs/apk/debug/app-debug.apk'
Installation failed due to: '-27'
Retry
```

**What I have so far**

Based on the google samples here [InstantApps Google samples](https://github.com/android/app-bundle-samples/tree/master/InstantApps) I created a new project and added a `Instant dynamic feature module`.
So my project has the following structure:

```
-app/manifest/AndroidManifest.xml
-app/<packagname>/MainActivity
-instant/manifest/AndroidManifest.xml
-instant/<packagname>/InstantActivity
```

Snippet of the `instant/manifest/AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<dist:module
    dist:instant="true"
    dist:title="@string/title_instant">
    <dist:delivery>
        <dist:install-time />
    </dist:delivery>

    <dist:fusing dist:include="false" />
</dist:module>

<application android:allowBackup="false">
    <activity android:name=".InstantActivity">
        <intent-filter
            android:autoVerify="true"
            android:order="2">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

            <data android:host="com.farmdok.multi.instant" />
            <data android:pathPrefix="/instant" />
            <data android:scheme="https" />
            <data android:scheme="http" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

The full code of that new project is here on my github: [InstantAppTest](https://github.com/geckogecko/instantAppTest)

This is how i run the normal app:

[image]

This is how i run the instant app:
[image]

Comment: This might help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57589248/installation-failed-due-to-null-android-studio-3-5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find the problem by installing the app over adb with:

```
adb install -r -t --full <installed-app.apk>
```

This gave me a more detailed error message:

```
adb: failed to install app-debug.apk: Failure [-27: Package <packagename>.instantapp new target sandbox 1 is incompatible with the previous value of2.]
```

So all I needed was to add:

```
android:targetSandboxVersion="2"
```

to the `Manifest` of the `app`