# APK installation failure on AVD

Tags: android, android-emulator, emulation, updates

yes I have looked at all the questions and answers and tried all solutions.

**NOTE** The APK was not installed on the emulator, so uninstalling it was not a valid option.

I'm Using Android Studio 4.1.3, [Screenshot of Android Version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tte51.png)

This just happened after an Emulator Update, I have also tried various emulators

```
04/03 16:12:16: Launching 'app' on Pixel 4 API R.
Installation did not succeed.
The application could not be installed: INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_NOT_APK

List of apks:
[0] 'C:\Users\xxx\AndroidStudioProjects\MyApp\app\build\outputs\apk\debug\app-debug.apk'
Installation failed due to: 'null'
```

It installs and runs fine on my Samsung A50, but as can be seen, does not install on emulator.

I have deleted emulator, created a new device etc, and performed all recommendations here [Installation failed due to: 'null' - Android Studio 3.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57589248/installation-failed-due-to-null-android-studio-3-5)

Here is the event log

```
16:45   Failed to commit install session 1484155752 with command cmd package install-commit 1484155752. Error: INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_NOT_APK: Failed parse during installPackageLI: Failed to parse base APK: /data/app/vmdl1484155752.tmp/base.apk

16:45   Session 'app': Installation did not succeed.
            The application could not be installed: INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_NOT_APK
            Retry

16:45   Error
            Installation did not succeed.
            The application could not be installed: INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_NOT_APK
            Retry

16:45   Failed to start monitoring emulator-5554
```

1. Is there a bug in the emulator update
2. Can I roll it back
3. How else can I fix this.

Comment: Did you tried changing the build type?

Comment: @Eyosiyas, yes, thank you, no difference

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the responses, I wound back the minSdkVersion to 29 and targetSdkVersion to 29 and the problem seems to be fixed, might be a bug with R